# Executing a binary on Linux web server through PHP's exec

Tags: php, linux, exec

#### UPDATE

My directory structure is as follows

```
http://domainname.com/developer/clientName/ppt/phantom/    // inside this phantom folder, all files are present
```

After having a chat with Bass Jobsen and after having a look at the server error logs, I found this listed in the logs

```
[Tue Apr 23 08:31:34 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] sh: line 1: 29443 
Segmentation fault /home/xyz/public_html/developer/clientName/ppt/phantom/phantomjs --version 2>&1
```

==================================================================================

#### SUMMARY

I'm trying to execute a binary on my server. The binary is called `phantomJS` which is used mainly to create screenshots of a webpage.

I logged into my cPanel and found the following information about my server:

```
Operating system : Linux
Architecture     : i686
```

So I went ahead and downloaded `phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-i686.tar.bz2` from the phantomJS website. I uploaded the `phantomjs` file which was located inside the `bin` folder of the download (I just uploaded one file which was named as `phantomjs` and was approx 38 MB in size. I'm assuming I don't need any other files that came with the download. There was an `examples` folder and some `ReadMe`s and other `.txt` files)

I also uploaded three more files to the same folder in which `phantomjs` was present:

1. `test.php` (which is the main file which will be executed in the
   browser)
2. `test.js` (which contains the code to start phantomjs)
3. `createScreenshot.php` (which contains code that outputs some HTML)

So all the files are in the same folder. Thus, there shouldn't a problem arising out due to a wrong path.

#### test.php

```
exec('phantomjs test.js');
```

#### test.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'createScreenshot.php';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    page.render('test.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

#### createScreenshot.php

```
echo '<h1>This should be converted to an image</h1>';
```

### The Problem

Now when I browse to `www.mydomain.com/test/test.php`, all I get is a blank page, which is fine as the only thing that should happen is the creation of an image in the `test` folder, but that never happens. No error is being output. I also tried putting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` inside `test.php`, but still no error was shown, just a blank page.

#### Debugging

I decided to test whether `exec` is at all enabled on my server. I did so by using

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

This printed out my cPanel username. So this means `exec` is working.

The next thing I did was to check for folder permissions. `test` folder had `755` permission and so did `phantomjs`. I tried changing both to `777` but that didn't help either.

This makes me believe that something is wrong with `phantomjs` file. I'm out of ideas on what to try next. I sure think that I downloaded the correct package from the phantomJS website (`phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-i686.tar.bz2`).

Is there anything else that I can do to debug the issue?

#### More Debugging

Running

```
echo exec("ls -lh");
```

printed out

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 abc abc 1.8K Apr 6 05:15 third-party.txt
```

This `third-party.txt` is in the folder which holds the `phantomjs` binary, but I wonder why only one file name was printed. There are php and js files too in the same folder as `third-party.txt`. Not really sure `1` stands for in the above output though.

Comment: Do you know if `phantomjs` is in your PHP executable path? If not, you might want to try to find it and use absolute paths for it (`locate phantomjs` or alternative)

Comment: PHP is typically inheriting the path from the user it is run as (typically `/usr/bin, /usr/local/bin`). What you need to check is if `phantomjs` actually is in those. If it isn't, you'll need to refer to its absolute path (i.e. exactly where it is). `locate phantomjs` might give back its location.

Comment: As you uploaded it to the same folder as your script, trying as path the following: `dirname(__FILE__)."/phantomjs"` may very well prove to work.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but do you mean trying out `echo exec(dirname(__FILE__)."/phantomjs")` ?

Comment: Yes, if phantomjs is in the same folder as your PHP script. Or the errors/warnings/notices that follow.

Comment: Output of `exec("ls -lh")`, please. It would really help if you could actually track down the full path of phantomjs - it is your server, after all, and I don't have a crystal ball nearby.

Comment: Yes I understand. I actually appreciate you tolerating my noobness and not losing patience. Updated my answer with output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a binary file is uploaded via FTP, it may become corrupted due the the FTP client changing the line endings inside the file.

To fix the issue, change the transfer mode to binary (in FileZilla: Transfer -> Transfer type -> Binary).

[[source]](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=289)

Comment: Perfect. That was indeed the issue. The binary was getting corrupted while transferring through Filezilla. You're a life saver. I'd been struggling with this issue for the past one week.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same you have done.

test.php:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo exec('./phantomjs-1.9.0-linux-i686/bin/phantomjs ./test.js 2>&1');
exit;
```

Instead of `./` i could also use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

my test.js:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function () {
page.render('github.png');
phantom.exit();
});
```

All files are in my document root (/var/www/). Test.php run from the webserver so does phantomjs when called via `exec()`. the user which runs the webserver (www-data needs rights) to write 'github.png'. To get this i use chmod 0777 /var/www/. Now all works fine.

Without the chmod test.php give me a blank page. phantomjs doesn't print errors.

NB don't change the right of your root dir in a production environment. Create new dir for your screenshots and chmod this and cahnge the save path in test.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created a new folder for the images, made the permission as `777` and updated the path in the `.js` file. It still didn't work. Maybe the user running the webserver doesn't have the rights. Is there a way to find if that is exactly the problem? Or anything that can be done through cPanel to add rights to the user?

Comment: you can write a new file with http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php to your images dir a check the user / group it get

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `check the user/group it get`. I created a new text file inside the folder where the screenshot is supposed to save. I then ran a simple `fwrite` no that newly created text file. It was successful. The file did get written.

Comment: if fwrite can write,phantomjs also could what is the output of `echo exec('./phantomjs --version 2>&1');`

Comment: I get `sh: phantomjs: command not found` Also I had to remove `./` from `./phantomjs --version 2>&1` to get that message displayed

Comment: okay try `echo exec($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/phantomjs --version 2>&1');` if test.php and phantomjs are not in the root dir add the dir too, like `echo exec($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/{youtestdir}/phantomjs --version 2>&1');` replace {yourtestdir} with the dir

Comment: `No such file or directory` . So it's clear that it is not able to find the binary at the place where we are telling it to look.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28732/discussion-between-bass-jobsen-and-asprin)

Comment: Hey Bass. Just thought of letting you know what the problem was. It was indeed a case of corrupted binary which was caused due to Filezilla

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the IMAGEMAGICK library when running it by `exec`. The strange thing was that **exec** seems not to be able to correctly find the paths of some executables. So, instead of using just `convert` I had to use the full application path `/usr/bin/convert`.
To find the full application path type the following in the terminal:

```
type -a YOUR_COMMAND
```

One more advice: use the optional parameters of the PHP's **exec** command, here is the definition from the manual:

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

I was able to track my problem with the help of the third parameter, which returns the status of the executed statement. If you get 127 as status you definitely have to use the full path to the application!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me check it and I'll get back to you with the output

Comment: I did `$abc = exec('phantomjs table1.js', $op, $err);`. The output of `$abc` was 11. Any idea what this means?

Comment: The output depends on the executed command, I haven't used phantomjs so far and cannot help you with that. Do you have ssh access to your server? If yes, try the command you want to execute from php directly in the terminal. If it works, then you probably passed some of the options from php wrong (filepaths etc...), if not, then something is wrong with the executed application and php has nothing to so with it

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the optional parameters of `exec` That eventually helped me to get to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you use exec or any of its sister functions, try specifying the file with an **absolute** path -> exec, shell_exec, etc **DO NOT WORK** on my servers with a relative path.

If youre on shared hosting it'll be different of course, but something like:

```
exec('/var/www/html/script')
//or if youre on a shared server it would be something more like
exec('/user2342jh/www-docs/html')
```

I went through a bit of a hair-pulling situation years ago working with this very type of thing.

Comment: Ok, I hear you, but if I were you, I'd make a simple PHP script that writes to a file for testing and check the absolute and relative paths, because IK'm almost 100% certain that, unless your host has it configured as such, you'll need an absolute path.  I just did this two days ago yet again, calling a python script from exec.

Comment: It's okay. I got it figured out. The culprit was Filezilla :) Thanks for taking time to answer though. +1